qt.qpa.xcb: and qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found
this is my first post here. I am having issues with multiple programs. Sorry if I explain things wrong, I just started using linux more and have been mostly self taught.
Here is the original issue I was having when I tried to open a package called imod:
administrator@kemdla:~/Documents$ imod
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.


From other threads of people having this issue I first tried:
    sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0

and
    sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-0

with no success. Then I ran:
    sudo apt-get install libqt5x11extras5

And I get this result when I try to open the imod package.
administrator@kemdla:/$ imod
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/local/IMOD/lib/imodplug/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/local/IMOD/lib/imodplug/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/local/imod_4.11.25/lib/imodplug/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/local/imod_4.11.25/bin/realbin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/local/imod_4.11.25/lib/imodplug/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
administrator@kemdla:/$ QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/local/IMOD/lib/imodplug/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/local/IMOD/lib/imodplug/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/local/imod_4.11.25/lib/imodplug/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/local/imod_4.11.25/bin/realbin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/local/imod_4.11.25/lib/imodplug/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Providing your Ubuntu product & release is always helpful; it allows us to understand what software stack you're using, and is pretty essential for deb packages as versions are built for specific releases.  What are you running?
